# Удаленная отладка android устройства

Tags: android, windows, winforms

Можно ли, чтобы удаленный компьютер, на который я зашел через программу удаленного доступа, обнаружил android устройство, которое подключено через кабель usb к компьютеру через который я зашел на удаленный компьютер?

Comment: А подробнее? Что используете для удалённого доступа?

Comment: Программа для удаленного доступа может быть любая, а меня интересует нужна ли какая-то программа для такого распознавания или это как-то по-другому сделать можно?

Comment: на общий вопрос могу ответить только также обобщённо.
раз http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/
два http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html

Answer (score 0):

Если удаленный компьютер это Windows server не ниже 2008 R2. Там есть функция RemoteFX, вот с помощью нее можно.

Comment: Нет, компьютер win 8